# Need to resend event confirmation email

Tags: civievent, email, confirmation

We need to be able to resend individual event confirmation emails (e.g. corrections to the registration, sometimes not received etc.).
Up till last year's event in August this was no problem. There was a check box on the participant record to allow you to resend upon saving the record.
Since upgrading to our current version CiviCRM 5.22.0 this appears no longer an option. Has this been moved elsewhere?
For our event (https://www.capelcarshow.com/show-registration/) it is a critical feature. We are really in problems without it. Any suggestions or help out there?

Comment: i checked https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ site, i see the 'Send Confirmation and Receip' checkbox on Edit participant record and 'Send Receipt' checkbox on linked payment record (edit mode).

Comment: @SunilPawar if you post this as an answer (ideally with screenshot) I would upvote it!

Comment: Well that's really odd: I see it on some participation records on the demo site, but not all. Check this one out: Bachman, Rebekah, Rain-forest Cup Youth Soccer Tournament.

Comment: GIven the above where in some cases the check box shows (to send confirmation and receipt), does any one know or understand what the triggers are for this to show or not show?

Answer (score 5):

OK - I have now found the setting. The functionality has changed.

Go to 'view Event Participation' -> click 'change selections' -> now the checkbox is visible and an email can be generated.

Thanks